# AngularJS accessing object values globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm having a problem with the following code that is

```
   var  facilities_list;
   facilities_list= $http({

               url: 'facilitiesList_api.php', 
               method: "GET",
               params: {
                   "api":"TRUE","uid":"1","functionName" : "getUserFacilitiesList",
                       },
              headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }
           }).success(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                 console.log(facilities_list.$$state.toSource()); // line x


          });
        console.log(facilities_list.$$state.toSource());  //line y
```

I'm trying to print same value in line x and line y but line y contents are not same as contents in line x . I have also tried making facilities_list into $scope.facilities_list still it is showing undefined .
and the output of line x are

```
    ({status:1, pending:(void 0), value:{data:[{id:"3", name:"Your  Name Here", color:"#99FFFF"}], status:200, headers:(function (c){
    "use strict";
    a||(a=Lc(b));return c?a[S(c)]||null:a}), config:        
    {method:"GET",         
     transformRequest:[(function (a){
    "use strict";
     return R(a)&&"[object File]"!==Ea.call(a)&&"
    [object Blob]"!==Ea.call(a)?ra(a):a})], 
    transformResponse:[(function (d){
     "use strict";
    F(d)&&(d=d.replace(c,""),
    b.test(d)&&a.test(d)&&(d=hc(d)));
    return d})],         
    url:"http://localhost/oe/facilitiesList_api.php",         
    params:{api:"TRUE",        
    uid:"1",         
    functionName:"getUserFacilitiesList"},
     headers:{Accept:"application/json, 
    text/plain, */*",        
     Authorization:"Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA=="}},
     statusText:"OK"}, processScheduled:false})
```

and for line y is

```
   ({status:0, pending:[[{promise:{$$state:{status:0}}, 
     resolve: (function (c){
     "use strict";
     b.call(a,c)}), reject:(function (c){
     "use strict";
     b.call(a,c)}), notify:(function (c){
     "use strict";
     b.call(a,c)})}, (function (b){
     "use strict";
     a(b.data,b.status,b.headers,c)}), (void 0), (void 0)]]})
```

I want to use that facilities_list.$$state.value.data.id from line x globally so i printed it outside on line y but .value.data is not available in the output .
So please guide me ...

Comment: `$http` returns a `promise` which `success` function is called asynchronous. It  may happened something between two `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

First you **declare** facilities_list as

```
var facilities_list
```

Then you assign asynchronious method to this variable..($http) So:

Line X contains information about this variable cause you call it after rest call succeed.

Line Y is invoked right after asyn method (which isnt resolved for this moment), that's why your variable is undefined.
Check please this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp
its pretty much this same situation.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah I've already did that before posting here  but  still no use. thanks. plzz help